# getting value from Enum in knockout

Tags: c#, knockout.js, controller

In my controller i created method like

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<MyEnum> GetMyEnum()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>();
    }
```

Then in my knockout i am trying to get it like

```
  $.getJSON(BASE_PATH + 'mycontroller/GetMyEnum', function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                self.myEnumbservable.push({ "key": key, "value": value });
            });

        });
```

Here is Enum

```
  public enum TypeOfGoodsEnum
{
    Cat= 10, 
    Dog= 20

}
```

I am able to hit controller but i dont get anything in knockout. Can someone guide me. I am new using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return dictionary to achieve what you are trying to do here:

```
[HttpGet]
public IDictionary<string, int> GetMyEnum()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
            .Cast<MyEnum>()
            .ToDictionary(t => t.ToString(), t => (int)t);
}
```

Additionally you have to edit the knockout part:

```
 $.getJSON(BASE_PATH + 'mycontroller/GetMyEnum', function (data) {
        var enumArray = [];
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            enumArray.push({ "key": key, "value": value });
        });
        self.myEnumbservable(enumArray);
    });
```

Comment: Not sure why its not going inside loop after it hits controller.

Comment: when i changed return like return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection) then its working. why_

Comment: @Happy you cannot simply return list of enums from your controller. Either you have to convert them or use StringEnumConverter. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I removed the loop and instead used ToDictionary which is more elegant.